# is there a solution to search in json a key in opensearch/elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

is there a method to search in elasticsearch or opensearch in a keyword field :

the keyword field "data" contains a json.dumps of dict i.e :

```
"data" : "{\"Artificial intelligence\" : {...} , \"Cars\" : {...} }"
```

i want to search by key in my query
how can we do this without reindexing documents
a method like right a script in query to trasnform str  to dict then search in the keys of dict ..

a method like right a script in query to trasnform str  to dict then search in the keys of dict ..

Comment: You might not need to reindex but at least update your index in order to extract those fields from the JSON string. Would that be a viable alternative for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reindex your data, at least you should update your index in order to extract those fields from the JSON string. Anything else would just be like sticking a plaster on a wooden leg.

First, create an ingest pipeline with a [`json` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/json-processor.html), like this:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/json-parser
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "json" : {
        "field" : "date",
        "target_field" : "json_data"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, simply update your index in place using that ingest pipeline:

```
POST your-index/_update_by_query?pipeline=json-parser&wait_for_completion=false
```

If your index is small you can remove `wait_for_completion=false`. Otherwise keep it as it will run the update in the background and you'll be able to monitor the progress using the `<task_id>` that is returned to you from the  call with the following command

```
GET _tasks/<task_id>
```

When the task is done and your index has been updated, the JSON data will have been parsed an indexed into their own fields inside the `json_data` object that you can now query using term/match queries.

Ideally, you should also modify your indexing client to run through the same pipeline so that the JSON data is parsed on the fly.

A word of caution though: before running the update, you might need to update your mapping in order to properly set the types of the fields (text, keyword, dates, etc.) extracted from the JSON before they get extracted, otherwise you won't be able to change them afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

In OpenSearch/Elasticsearch, you can search for documents based on values within a JSON field using various query types. However, searching by keys within a JSON object is not straightforward and typically requires a reindexing or preprocessing step. Here are some options to consider:

1. **Reindexing with Mapping Changes:**
   The most efficient way to search by JSON keys is to reindex your documents with a mapping change. You can specify the fields within the JSON object as keyword fields in your mapping. This way, each key becomes a searchable keyword field, allowing you to search for documents based on specific keys.

   Here's an example of how you can create a mapping with keyword fields for specific keys:

   ```json
   {
     "mappings": {
       "properties": {
         "data": {
           "type": "object",
           "properties": {
             "Artificial intelligence": {
               "type": "keyword"
             },
             "Cars": {
               "type": "keyword"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   After reindexing with this mapping, you can use simple term queries to search for documents based on specific keys.
2. **Preprocessing Data During Ingestion:**
   If reindexing is not an option, you can preprocess the JSON data during document ingestion to create additional keyword fields for each JSON key. This would require custom code to parse the JSON and extract the keys, then add them as keyword fields. You would need to transform your data before indexing it into Elasticsearch.
3. **Scripted Fields:**
   Elasticsearch supports scripted fields, which allow you to run scripts at query time to transform or manipulate data. While this approach is less efficient, you could create a scripted field that extracts keys from the JSON object and then use a term query to search for documents. Note that this can be computationally expensive, especially for large datasets.

Here's a simplified example of a scripted field that extracts keys from the `data` field:

```json
{
  "script_fields": {
    "extracted_keys": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          def json_data = doc['data.keyword'].value;
          def keys = [];
          for (def entry : json_data.keySet()) {
            keys.add(entry);
          }
          return keys;
        """,
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you can use a term query to search for documents based on the extracted keys:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "extracted_keys": "Artificial intelligence"
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that the above approaches may have performance implications, especially if your dataset is large. Reindexing with a proper mapping is generally the recommended approach for efficient and scalable searches based on JSON keys.